# Vaadin View in CssLayout get 100% empty space

Tags: css, user-interface, vaadin

ˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍˍ
| Label | ComboBox| Button | 
 ˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉˉ
I have this structure. Label and Button have fixed size, but for comboBox i need full empty space width. CssLayout do not have ExpandRatio.

I can not use other type of layout by some reason.

Comment: It's normal that CSS use 100% of avail space. You have to use other layout type, or calculate/set it manually.

Comment: This structure in Table cell. Main task that it's necessary to use CssLayout. Combobox do not get full empty space. If setWidth("100%") for Combobox - he take width of column and move button to background(behind right column or border of table). 
AbsoluteLayout cann't use, because column get width dynamicaly and i can get column width only after rendering all table.